# jquery/javascript declare variable from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to loop through all inputs on my page and declare a variable for each using the the id as name. This is what i have tried without success

```
$('input').each(function(){
    eval( 'var'+$(this).attr('id')+'='+$(this).val());
});
```

Comment: why do you want those variables.... why can't you use an object

Comment: I am feeding the results into an existing script

Comment: @DouglasCottrell use JSON object, so you can use them in your code

Comment: output the string you're generating inside eval and you'll see: you're missing a space after `var` and quatation marks aroudn the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this see if this works :

```
   $('input').each(function(){
        window[this.id] = this.value;
    });
```

Comment: If you must do this, please do `window[this.id] = this.value;`.

Comment: @JohannesH. More to the point, even if we are using jQuery (and it isn't inherently a bad thing), it's still always a bad idea to do `$(this).attr('id')`.

Comment: @lonesomeday I DO consider using jQuery for tasks that are not any more complex without it a bad thing. It's awfully slow - see test case linked in my answer. But you sill got a point of course ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').each(function(){ 
   window[this.id]=this.value;
});
```

Since  all variables are object of window,  you can initiate variables like this

Comment: +1 for not using jQuery for getting the ID. But there is still no reason to use it for the loop...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without ANY jQuery. Plain old Javascript. [Way faster](http://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbytagname/44), easier to read, no drawbacks. Jeez, why did all people start learning jQuery before they even got the basics?

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0 ; i < inputs.length ; i++ ) {
    window[inputs[i].id] = inputs[i].value;
}
```

In recent versions of all majot browsers, you can do the same thing using `querySelectorAll()`. It is more flexible, but almost as slow as jQuery.

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (var i = 0 ; i < inputs.length ; i++ ) {
    window[inputs[i].id] = inputs[i].value;
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting performance comparison, though in practical terms not overwhelming, in my opinion (unless we're doing *a lot* of tests on *a lot* of data). But I have to say, I disagree that your loops are easier to read! If I were doing this in my own code (which I wouldn't, because it's inherently stupid) I would use jQuery for the selection and loop in almost all circumstances, providing it was already loaded.

Comment: @lonesomeday If you don't like the loop, use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach - it almost looks like jQUery afterwards (only the function names are a bit longer). `document.getELementsByTagName('input').forEach(function (element) { /*...*/ });`

DOn'T get me wrong, I do use jQUery myself, especiall when dealing with AJAX. SO if it's loaded anyway, it's ok to be lazy and us it for simple tasks. But when I see people using jQuery for literally everything, I always get curious if they even know plain JS.

Comment: That won't work, though, because `getElementsByTagName` doesn't return an array. But you're right that learning how to do things the DOM way is always good for JS developers, even if they always use jQuery.

Comment: Oh. Yes, you're right, NodeLists are not arrays. Sorry, my bad!